Getting Listener issue during deployment of Oracle via kustomize
pod is encountering an issue where it cannot connect to the Oracle Database listener. Tets pod stuck in Error state and when I saw logs I am getting this logs with erros :-
[ec2-user@ip-10-211-28-63 oracle-db]$ kubectl logs release-name-connection-test -n oraclelatest
cmdret=1, status=ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where  ::= [/][@<connect_identifier>]
 ::= [][/][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where  ::= [/][@<connect_identifier>]
 ::= [][/][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
Please give me suggestions where I have to make changes.
This are all resources
[ec2-user@ip-10-211-28-63 oracle-db]$ kubectl get all -n oraclelatest
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/release-name-connection-test              0/1     Error     0          37h
pod/release-name-oracle-db-7846d76d65-4dc9b   1/1     Running   0          37h
NAME                             TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
service/release-name-oracle-db   NodePort   172.20.122.137           1521:31147/TCP,5500:31932/TCP   42h
NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/release-name-oracle-db   1/1     1            1           37h
NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/release-name-oracle-db-7846d76d65   1         1         1       37h
[ec2-user@ip-10-211-28-63 oracle-db]$
Give me exact solution on this, I tried to solve this from google and chatgpt but unable to solve this.
